# How to get foreign key class object using primary key class object in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-one

I am having requirement as get a foreign key class object using primary key class object in Hibernate.

```
Example:

Class A {
 Id A_id; //primary key
    String name;
}
Class B {


  Id B_id; //primary key
    Id A_id; //Foreign key
    String name; 
}
```

Noe I want to get the object of Class B using Class A's object using Hibernate mapping.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I want to get the Class B's object using A_id not Class A's object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use hibernate relations annotations:

```
Class A {
    @Id
    Id A_id; //primary key

    String name;
}
Class B {
    @Id
    Id B_id; //primary key

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="a_id", nullable=false)
    A a; //Foreign key

    String name; 
}
```

Notes:

- I assumed, that your relation is many-to-one, if it's not you should use another annotation (see @OneToOne and @OneToMany in hibernate/jpa documentation)
- Remember to properly annotate rest of your code (eg. @Entity and @Table annotations in your classes)
- Your Id's should have proper type (in most cases it's long)

EDIT:

```
Class A {
    @Id
    Id A_id; //primary key

    String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="a_id")
    B b;

}
```

where "a_id" is the name of foreign key column in B table. Because it's one-to-one relation, you need to ensure that every single A entity can be associated with only one B entity. Otherwise, you should use one-to-many relation and return set or list of B's.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I need to fetch the Class B's object using A_id field(foreign key) when I call the a.getB(using A class object) I should get B class object